# Find match within a first match

Tags: regex

I have the following string

```
abc123+InterestingValue+def456
```

I want to get the InterestingValue only, I am using this regex

```
\+.*\+
```

but the output it still includes the + characters

Is there a way to search for a string between the + characters, then search again for anything that is not a + character?

Comment: Use a capture group or look behind + lookahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookarounds.

```
(?<=\+)[^+]*(?=\+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lNuOzb/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a positive lookahead and a positive lookbehind (more info about these [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)). Basically, a positive lookbehind tells the engine "this match has to come before the next match", and a positive lookahead tells the engine "this has to come after the previous match". Neither of them actually match the pattern they're looking for though.

A positive lookbehind is  a group beginning with `?<=` and a positive lookahead is a group beginning with `?=`. Adding these to your existing expression would look like this:

```
(?<=\+).*(?=\+)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/J9QvJx/1)

Answer (score 2):

If it should be the first match, you can use a capture group with an anchor:

```
^[^+]*\+([^+]+)\+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^+]*` Optionally match any char except `+` using a negated character class
- `\+` Match literally
- `([^+]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars other than `+`
- `\+` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DHxaKn/1)